# Allow new users to point out a referring user (instead of referral links)

Tags: feature-request, referrals

When recommending a SE site to friends or colleagues, I will always pass on the "pure" site link instead of a referral link. In my eyes, referral links always have something slightly sleazy about them, even if there is no material profit involved for the referrer.

I personally don't particularly care for the promoter badges, so I will happily continue passing on the pure links. But in general, how about having a referral field when a new user signs up? Like so:

> Did an existing user of the site recommend coming here? If so, please enter their name or user ID: __________________________________________

The text field would trigger a drop-down identical to the search field on the "Users" page.

This way, one could promote the site without having to pass on referral links.

Obviously, this method would have a built-in ratio of lost referrals (e.g. when the user doesn't find their friend in the users list), and only users who actually bother *signing up* can be identified that way. But it would be a much cleaner way.

Note that this would be to **complement** the existing referral link functionality, not to replace it.

Comment: so... This way the site gets to look sleezy while you stay clean?

Comment: @Shog why would this make the site look sleazy?

Comment: because right now, "signing up" amounts to little more than entering your OpenID and... Well, that's it. It's a one-entry-field sign-up, it's beautiful - it's actually *more typing* to post without an account! This... changes that.

Comment: @Shog mmm, it *could* be made a voluntary profile field that gets entered once - along with all the other information - and then disappears.

Comment: @Shog9: it could be an option *after* you've signed up. Something like: "Get 100 points if you enter a referral code".